# TensorFlow, Keras, Flask - Unable to run my keras model as web app via flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, tensor

I've been working on a Machine learning model for my college project lately that accepts health factors from the user and supplies it to a CNN and the CNN tells the user the onset of them having diabetes in coming years. I've already written a keras model and saved it as hdf5 format. I've checked it running locally the saved model makes fine prediction. I want to run this model via a web application, hence I've been working on flask for the past couple of days. I've written code for flask app.py and index.html

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import request
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from flask import jsonify
import os
import re
import sys

# init model directory
MODEL_DIR = './models'
result=''

#init Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

#load the compiled model.
print("Loading model")
model = load_model(os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, 'classifier_model.hdf5'))

scaler= MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

#routing for home page
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('index.html')

if request.method == 'POST':
    weight=float(request.form['weight'])
    height=float(request.form['height'])
    gluc=float(request.form['glucose')])
    bp=float(request.form['bp'])
    age=float(request.form['age'])
    height=height/100
    bmi=weight/(height*height)
    predict_data=np.array([[gluc, bp, bmi, age],[103,80,19.4,22]])
    scaled_predict_data=scaler.fit_transform((predict_data))
    round_predict = 
model.predict_classes(scaled_predict_data,verbose=0)
    res=np.array_str(round_predict[0])

    return render_template('index.html', value=res)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    port= int(os.environ.get('PORT',8080))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port,debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script >
      var value= {{value}}
    </script>

</head>>
<body>

  <form  method = "POST">
     <p>Weight <input type = "number" name = "weight" /></p>
     <p>Height(CM) <input type = "number" name = "height" /></p>
     <p>Glucose(mg/dL) <input type = "number" name = "glucose" /></p>
     <p>Blood Pressure <input type ="number" name = "bp" /></p>
     <p>Age <input type ="number" name = "age" /></p>
     <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p><br>
     Output: {{ value }}<br>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Now when I run the app.py code, everything runs fine and index.html is rendered but when I hit the submit button I get this error message:
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_3/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Will switching to theano backend help?

Any help would be highly appreciated. This is my college project and the submission date has already passed. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problem and found that one of the possible solutions is to specify graph explicitly. Note that this is TensorFlow-specific solution, so is not quite portable.

```
import tensorflow as tf

...

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    print("Loading model")
    model = load_model(os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, 'classifier_model.hdf5'))

...

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    ...

    with g.as_default():
        round_predict = model.predict_classes(scaled_predict_data,verbose=0)

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Changing keras backend to theano did the trick. Theano backend can be changed via keras.json file in keras directory.